# Are what-cha and arent-cha examples of elision?

Tags: contractions, phonology, phonetics, language-formation, yod-coalescence

Are these words examples of elision? What effect do they create? If a child says them what does this suggest about their language development?
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Not "elision". That's way too general, and just means something's missing, without stating what, or where, or how it happened. The frequent contractions of _What are you_ and _Aren't you_ to /'wətʃə/ and /'arntʃə/ (spelled variously -- there is no standard spelling for noncanonic contractions) are examples of Assimilation. Contraction to _What're you_ /'wətryu/ fusing to /'wətʃu/ (because /tr/ is retroflexed and indistinguishable in speech from /tʃr/ -- try distinguising _true_ and _chew_), and then final /u/ reducing to /ə/ gives you "what-cha". Similar story for "arent-cha".

Comment: @JohnLawler - When my eldest was learning to read/write, he insisted on writing *train* as *chrain*. He eventually explained, "No, choo-choo-chrain!"

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you for clearing that up for me. Do you happen to have any thoughts on why children use assimilation particularity with regard to "what-cha" and "aren't-cha"?

Comment: Do they? Everybody uses assimilation all the time, kids included. When you study phonetics, you'll find hundreds of other places where it occurs; and hundreds of other phenomena besides assimilation, too. Though it **is** awfully common.

Comment: @JohnLawler The coronal consonants all do take a beating — palatalization, affricatization, and more — when followed by high vowels or glides in all forms of speech, and not just across morphemic boundaries, either. I’m thinking of what the long years have done to words like *conscience, coercion, contortion, natural, sure, sugar, casual, censure, pressure, mission, Asia, treasure, evasion, erosion, elation*. It’s so common that it is more noted in its absence, like when people bend over backwards to **stop** it from happening naturally in words like *issue* or *tissue* — or *didju*.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, I'm in consultation with a bunch of linguists who're writing a new HBO series on Proto-Indo-European etymology called _Game of Phones_.

Comment: @JohnLawler, SRK But the most important factor's the one you missed out /t/ and /j/. /wɒtʃə dɪd/ never had an /r/ in the fist place. After all where's the post-'t' /r/ in "aren't you"? Or where's the /r/ in "What you" i.e. "What you need". /r/ plays no role in the yod-coalescence in these examples. Sorry :(

Comment: Correct. A postvocalic /r/ is not the same as a postconsonantal one. But straighforward yodation does the job just as well. Like I said, "similar story". Not the same story.

Comment: I believe 'what-cha' is normally written as 'wotcha', if that's any help. Which it probably isn't.

Comment: @DJClayworth _Wotcha_ or _wotcher_ usually means ‘what cheer’, as in the somewhat quaint greeting (cf. Tonks in the _Harry Potter_ series: “Wotcher, Harry?”. I don’t recall seeing the contracted form of ‘what [are] you’ spelled any other way than _whatcha_.

Comment: @JohnLawler /tʃr/ and /tr/ are certainly distinct to me, though I suspect not in very rapid speech. If we’re talking about _true/chew_, where it’s /tr/ versus /tʃ/ with no /r/ at all, the difference is even greater, and that distinction would be maintained even in rapid speech. Only time I’d not distinguish those would be while in a post-dentist drug-induced stupor.

Comment: @srk I'm writing you a full-blown answer including excerpts from Her Majesty, Queen Elisabeth II of England's own speech and a link to a video of her speaking -so please come back and have a look at it in a bit!! :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Distinguishing /tʃr/ and /tr/ may well be instinct for you, but I don’t know if it would be were you a monoglot. The accounts of children not understanding why *tree* is not spelled *chree* “like it sounds” derive from real life, and are not uncommon in English-only speakers of certain accent characteristics like those who say [tʃɻʷ]. You won’t find any minimal pairs in English between words starting with /tʃr/ and those starting with /tr/, because there in fact exists not a single English word spelled *chr-* that isn’t pronounced /kr/. And yes, I did look. :)

Comment: @tchrist You do get near-minimal pairs like “betrayal” and “bitch, rail…” (not a good example, but you get my drift. 7 AM is way too early to think of good examples).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I can see plenty of folks thinking that *betrayal*, *beach rail*, *beet rail*, and *bee trail* all sound pretty close to alike when **they** say them (that is, all have [tʃ] there), even though I am not one who does so when I say them myself: no Rallidae were beaten on my watch.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit in order that the question is coherent and matches the existing answers. Please don't change a question beyond recognition -- and in this case, the result of the edit would normally be instantly closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 3):

It's probably helpful to define some terms here:

***Elision***

This involves the complete omission of individual sounds. It can happen at word boundaries or word internally. An example would be the omission of /d/ in the word *friendly*, so that it sounds like *frenly*:

- He's very friendly --> /hiz 'veri 'frenli/.

***Assimilation***

This is an altogether different process. This is when two sounds occur next to each other. One of the sounds changes to a different phoneme and becomes more like the sound it's next to. In other words, it assimilates properties of the sound it's juxtaposed with.

So, for example, when we say the word *input*, the /n/, which is highly unstable, takes on the bilabial quality of the /p/ and becomes /m/. In normal speech therefore the word *input* is usually pronounced /ɪmpʊt/.

***Coalescent assimilation***

This is really a quite different phenomenon from normal assimilation. Occasionally, when we have two sounds next two each other the adjustments we need to make to be able pronounce them in succession result in a third completely different sound which replaces both of the original two. One such example of this is when we have /z/ followed by /j/ (the sound represented by the letter 'y'). These are often replaced by the sound, /ʒ/ (the middle consonant in vision). So in the sequence *these yours* we occasionally get:

- Are these yours --> /ə ði:ʒɔ:z/

Here /ʒ/ is acting both as the last consonant in *these* and the first in *yours*. Arguably, we also get this word type of coalescence internally in words like *leisure* /'leʒə/.

***The Original Poster's example phrases***.

The Original Poster's question was about the phrases  "whatcha" and "aren'tcha". These are forms of *what you* and *aren't you*. In as much as *whatcha* ever occurs as a form of the phrase "what are you", for example in *what are you gonna do about it*, it only occurs in sentences where the auxiliary *are* has been ellipted. In other words the whole word *are* is completely missing: *watcha* only occurs as a form of ***what you*** gonna to do about it

Both of these phrases are examples of coalescent assimilation, not elision or regular assimilation. This particular type of coalescence is often called *yod coalescence*. When the sound /t/ occurs before the sound /j/ in normal speech there is a tendency for them to be replaced by the sound /tʃ/ as in **ch**in. In the sequences *wha**t y**ou* and *aren**t y**ou* we find /t/ and /j/ at the junction of the two words:

- /wɒt ju/ and /'a:nt ju/ [British English] --> /wɒtʃu/ and  /'ɑ:ntʃu/
- /wʌt ju/ and /'ɑrnt ju/ [General American] --> /wʌtʃu/ and  /'ɑrntʃu/

In casual speech the /u/'s at the end there may turn into /ə/, which is the *whatcha* and *arentcha* in the OP's question.

One might be tempted to think that the /wʌtʃu/ in American English comes from a  co-articulation of "what are you ..." /wʌt ər ju/ where the /t/ in *what* and the /r/ in *are* join together to give a post-alveolar apico affricate - which is very similar in sound to /tʃ/ (see John Lawler's comments under the original question). However, this is definitely not the case. There are two straightforward pieces of evidence. Firstly, this pronunciation occurs in British English in all the same environments as it does in General American, but British English doesn't have an /r/ sound in the word *are* at all. Secondly the "ch" sound in /wʌtʃu/ doesn't occur in American English in phrases like "what are *they* ...". If it was the /t/ and the /r/ that were producing the "ch" sound, it would obviously occur here too - but it doesn't.

***Yod coalescence in young people's speech***

The Original Poster was wondering why young people use yod coalescence, and what this says about their language development. Well, firstly it should be said that the /tʃ/ phoneme is one of the very last to be acquired by children. Children usually manage to master the following significantly earlier than they manage /tʃ/:

- / p, b, t, d, k, g, m, n, ŋ, f, v, s, z, h, w, l, j/

So the occurrence of /tʃ/ is a welcome sign in any young person's phonemic inventory.

More significantly, yod coalescence, although it is often thought of as "not proper" is in fact widespread across all standard varieties of English. It doesn't only occur with "what you" and "aren't you", it occurs commonly at any boundaries where we find /tj/ sequences.

To underline this point, linked at the bottom of this section here is a video of Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II talking about her working life. If you forward to the following stages of the video you will hear the Queen doing various "watchu"-type articulations:

- 05.22 "It's quite an old fashioned idea **thatchou** do put out the red carpet  - for the guest"
- 07.00 "You hope **thachour** going to get the, the ...
- 07.03 ... the answer **thatchou** want".
- 09.15 "You know. You know exactly **whatchour** going to be doing two months hence"
- 09.29 "You have to sort've work out in your mind the hard work, an then **whatchou** enjoy in retrospect ... "

Video link here: [Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lh1-9ww_HmM)

The upshot of this is that, young people should not be made to feel bad about yod coalescence, it's perfectly normal, standard English. The idea that yod coalescence is not a feature of standard Englishes is a myth promulgated by ne'er do well prescriptionists. Most people who think that they don't have yod coalescence as a feature of their normal speech, in actual fact, do.

Comment: In AmE, 'student' in deliberate articulated speech is pronounced /stu:dent/ (that is, not /stju:dent/). So there is no assimilation of /tj/ to /tʃ/. In regular AmE speech it becomes /stu:?nt/ or /stu:ent/ or a dental flap or whatever happens to the 'd'.

Comment: @Mitch There is **never, ever** any /e/ phoneme in *student*, so –1 to your comment for pretending there is.

Comment: @Mitch Quite right, I was thinking in British English of course. AmE doesn't have /tju/ or dju/ sequence that appears in GB words like tube, student, or . so you have /tu:b/ for example and we have /tʃu:b/.

Comment: @tchrist sure, in regular speech, the /n/ or /nt/ or /?nt/ or /dnt/ is by itself syllabic. But 'never' is a bit extreme. In deliberate articulate speech (which is admittedly rare) there is something of an /e/-like vowel.

Comment: @Mitch I think what tchrist is getting at, is that the vowel there, if there is one, will be a schwa /ə/. It will never be a /e/ as in "denture", for example. (In this position though there's very unlikely to be a vowel there, or at least in British English, because the tongue is already on the alvoelar ridge from the /d/ and it will just stay there for the /n/ while the velum shifts to allow air to pass through the nasal cavity).

Comment: /ɑrəntʃu/ has too many syllables: the schwa is spurious.  Also, you’ve gone and spelt ER2’s name wrong. She will not be amused.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks Am Eng not my strongest point. Thtas's what I'd have thought but nicked it off a uni website! Any other insights I should be aware of?

Comment: @tchrist 'Mrs. Windsor'?

Comment: @Mitch it's with a 'z'. I call her 'Betty' myself ... :)

Comment: The old kids’ joke “Knock knock. Who’s There?  Orange? Orange who? Orange ya glad I didn’t say banana!”  illustrates that the same thing happens in both sequences *aren’t you* and *orange you*: the [n] nasalizes the vowel a bit (gives it a *twang*) and gets somewhat lost in the collision, rendering rhymes especially challenging. Also, you cannot use a schwa in a stressed syllable: it has to be [ʌ], which is how we actually say it.

Comment: Both *what* and *that* each have stressed and unstressed variants. In the unstressed versions, they share a common vowel — the fully reduced schwa — but in the stressed ones, they do not. As a relative pronoun, *what* can be unstressed, but not in sentence-initial position as a *wh*-question word.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, - completely different to British English!

Comment: There is no /e/ in *denture*. Please stop writing that. It is the wrong phoneme.

Comment: T@tchrist There is in our transcription! And we invented the vowel quadrilateral in the first place! :  /ˈdentʃəz/ [denture](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dentures) And the reason for using the 'e' symbol for that phoneme is well described by Wells.

Comment: Then you have done it wrong, given that /e/ and /ɛ/ both exist phonemically in English. Minimal pairs are easily found. In any event, the OED has /ɛ/ in the stressed syllable of *denture*, and you should, too.

Comment: @tchrist Did you not see that that was the Cambridge Dictionary transcription? The link's right there ..

Comment: @tchrist What d'you mean they both exist, anyway? We use /e/ for that vowel and you guys tend to use /ɛ/. It's the same phoneme!!!

Comment: @Araucaria No, “you” do not. Please consult virtually any OED IPA transcription for what “you” do. Then go read about minimal pairs for those, too. Again, see the OED: *date* and *debt* do not sound like, and it is not the offglide that’s doing that. I am totally stunned that you pretend [e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) and [ɛ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) allophones of a single phoemic /e/. You just create confusion through your stubborn refusal to recognize established practice on these matters.

Comment: @tchrist  We don't use a single symbol to represent diphthongs, because it's, erm, not a very good idea - read - Wells. So, I checked to see if the OED has changed their transcription - and it hasn't: date /deɪt/ It says Brit: /deɪt/ U.S.: /deɪt/  Here's the link:[OED'date' transcription](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.is.ed.ac.uk/view/Entry/47416?rskey=biHnRB&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Comment: @tchrist You may find this useful for deciphering British English transcriptions. It's the standard system used by the majority of British English publications including academic journals: [Phonetic symbols for English](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/phoneticsymbolsforenglish.htm) Here is some notes on transcription by John Wells. Pages 8-11 explain the history of the transcription of English vowels in both American and British English [p.8-11 History of English vowel transcription](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/transcription-ELL.pdf).

Comment: @tchrist Here also's Well's discussion of International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) transcription. At the bottom, sections 6 and 7, you'll find a description of the Standard system, and a discussion of Upton's departures for the COD. Section 7's basically a summary of why Upton's changes have had little or no traction in academic journals or other British publications, apart from the changes to Square and Trap vowels, which were already on the cards, and which were recently adopted in Cruttenden's 2014 ed of Gimson. [IPA trans](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/phoneticsymbolsforenglish.htm)

Comment: Did you forget to check *debt*? **It is not /det/** and this is my point. Why won’t you acknowledge this?

Comment: @tchrist If you read the links above, you'll find that nobody has taken a blind bit of notice of what Upton did with Oxford in terms of changing the transcription of /e/ to /ɛ/. The Dress vowel is standardly /e/ in British English transcription, and Australian, NZ. (In SA both exist side by side). I can't use /ɛ/ in my professional life - either as an academic or as a teacher, because no one would be able to tell which system I was using. In Gen Am it makes sense to use /ɛ/  because Dress in Gen Am is much lower than British English. RP Dress is halfway between Cardinals 2-3 (used to be 2).

Comment: @tchrist It's not that I think /ɛ/ is 'bad' or something, it's just not what is standard for the transcription of British English. If the standard changes to /ɛ/ at any point, I'll use that - but it hasn't, not yet anyhow ... Here's the link to the 8th Edition of Gimson 2014. You can check out what's used there. 7th page in. [Gimson 2014](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=M2nMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT570&lpg=PT570&dq=wells+upton+transcription&source=bl&ots=GCGt0846Wj&sig=E4WQ8CiqI5VxhqQY2KaQYxrdtto&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sCcxVPDeLdDlavmDgPgH&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=wells%20upton%20transcription&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that "elision" is too general, given it refers specifically to omission of vowels, consonants or syllables. However, I'm not sure if it applies here, given that your example is more of a morphing of words into a hybrid phonetic contraction. Regarding why a child would say that, it appears to be part of learning language. It begins with phonetic mimicry, the attempt to duplicate what they hear, but due to inexperience, their initial attempts are slightly off (hence why kids say so many malapropisms; they sound close enough). They opt for the simpliest and most comfortable phrasing, as well as the swiftest pronunciation, which is why assimilation is common occurence. It's not limited to children. Many adults, especially those in accent-heavy regions, also do it. It's rectified by gentle and consistent correction and re-annunciation from the corrector. However, with aren't-cha and what-cha, I don't know that it's necessary, so long as they know the proper way to say it and aren't writing the words out like that.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a bit misleading that bit about correction. All the evidence shows that correction plays *no part at all* in the development of child speech. There's been hundreds of studies, and they all disprove it.

Comment: I'd be happy to read any of the studies you're referencing, though my personal experience with my own minor speech issues and with dealing my nephews seems to contradict that, though naturally that's only anecdotal evidence.