# Do we pronounce a "t" sound in negative contractions "n't"

Tags: pronunciation

I'm faced with difficulties how to pronounce contractions like don't, wouldn't, and etc. correctly.

Somehow I read from some grammar British student book that "t" is not pronounced but 
I didn't pay attention to that just because I think it's may be common for the UK (hi, pronunciation of "got") or depends on people (everyone to his taste).
Watching movies, shows it seemed to me that native speakers pronounce "t" but may be it's not strongly pronounced because of strong pronunciation of "d", "o".
Yesterday I watched a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dthn7A9AmaM where a lady talks we should miss the sound "t" in contractions "n't". I thought that's fine, I'll do.
But the another video I came across was that http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3xmedFIhm0 ....
Yes, it has a few views comparing to the previous link. But it has another opinion and the lady from the last video says that we should pronounce "t".
So, I don't know what to think about that. It's really strange. How is it possible ?

Comment: A link to another part of original question here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295649/how-to-pronounce-do-you-would-you-and-their-negative-contractions

Comment: Thanks for answers ! It would be nice to listen more opinions especially from native speakers.   
I don't want to start a holy war between citizens from different countries.
As a not native English speaker I appreciate ANY opinions. In the UK I would try talking like an Englishman, in the US - like an American and so on.   
I believe any used language is developing as a live organism and of course there can be differences even between people inside the same country.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the video, the lady's pronunciation is very clear. I'll look into it

Comment: Definitely depends on your region as well. Where I live, sometimes the 't' is pronounced so strongly that people spit... it doesn't taper off nicely the way the American 't' seems to.

Comment: @Julia thanks for your opinion ! Where are you from ?

Comment: I'm from New York City, and I fully pronounce the t in "--n't" contractions.

Comment: @andy thanks ! well... I'm really surprised ! When you meet a person who doesn't clear pronounce the "t" (or may be he/she doesn't pronounce it at all) how you get what that person say ? For example, if we are talking about the case when that person pronounce "can" or "can't", he/she is not from the UK and doesn't shake his/her head yes/no. You pay attention to words he/she put his/her accent (can **GO** (can) vs. **CAN** go (can't)) and it's not important whether that person say "t" or not, right ?

Comment: @Vadim It's a problem in AmE. Even for native speakers listening to another native speaker, the final 't' isn't enough, and the stress isn't enough so you're never sure if they're saying "I can't pick up the 100kg sofa off your chest" or "I can pick up the 100kg sofa off your chest".

Comment: @Mitch oh, man ! o_O so, how do native speakers understand what his opponent's just said ? Asking again or starting the next phrase like this "Let me get this straight, you are not able to pick up..." ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time and help ! It's a pity I didn't get opinions from people who live in Australia, Canada, New Zealand.... Anyway, Merry Christmas ! And Happy New Year ! :)

Comment: @Vadim usually you can hear the difference (by the hints others have noted). But sometimes not. Then you say like anybody: "Was that 'can' or 'cannot'?" Or something similar.

Comment: I just saw Rachel's video. She speaks the same accent that I do (the very common General American. She is explaining how people actually speak (in order to teach non-native speakers how to speak most naturally like native speakers). For GenAmE, she shows well that the 't' is hard to hear and hard to pronounce clearly. If you want to be unequivocally understood, you may want to overarticulate the 't' (in comparison to Rachel). But if you want to sound natural, you don't. (don't drop the 't' entirely unless you're speaking real fast).

Comment: @Araucaria I listened to both Rachel and Stacey and it seems like they are saying pretty much the same thing. Can you say anything in particular that Rachel says incorrectly?

Comment: @Araucaria People are voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based. I think it is because the title uses 'Should...'. If it were changed to 'Do English speakers...' do you think that would remove the 'opinion' based interpretation?

Comment: @Mitch We can certainly give it a go!

Comment: @Araucaria thanks! I could have done it right away but I wanted to see if there was any agreement first.

Comment: @Mitch I'll dig out one of her video's a bit later. About to leave the computer just now :)

Comment: @Araucaria Unfortunately, a downvote came shortly after changing the title. Argh.

Comment: I have to make an unreserved apology for not recommending Rachel's English. I'm afraid I was confusing Rachel with another Youtube English presenter. Rachel's English looks like a very fine channel indeed! I apologise for my confusion!

Comment: @Mitch Oops. Mea cupla maxima :( I was confusing Rachel with [Jennifer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vfmcwonndM&list=UUEKXieT70wByfvZwP1CxdPQ). I have have deleted my comment and rectified with  OP!

Comment: @Mitch That had 4 downvotes when I made the edit, so it *might* still stave off a close ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The /t/ in negative contractions in English can have three main realisations. In *decreasing* order of likelihood (all other things being equal):

- it can be a glottal stop
- it can be dropped altogether
- it can be a full [t]

It does not matter at all in negative contractions whether the following sound is a consonant or not in terms of dropping the /t/ altogether. It can easily be a vowel that follows.

So in terms of what native speakers actually do, by far the rarest realisation is with a canonical [t]. However, it is never *wrong* to use a normal [t] sound. Knowing that a [t] will usually not be present will greatly improve non-native speakers' listening skills though.

The other reason to be aware of the fact that there may not be a [t] present is that  it enforces that fact that it is *stress* which is the most important factor for distinguishing negative contractions from normal auxiliaries. Negative contractions are stressed in English, whereas other things being equal most auxiliaries aren't when occurring in positive sentences. So when trying to distinguish between *She can come* and *she can't come* we will listen out for the following rhythms:

- ba ba **BOM**
- ba **BOM** **BOM**

The first is what we expect from the positive polarity sentence. The second is the negative.

**Assimlatory processes**

The final [t] in negative contractions may be affected by the sounds following it.

For example, if the word following the contraction normally starts with [j], as in the first sound in *you*, then the /t/ and the /j/ may coalesce to form an new affricate sound, /tʃ/. This is the first sound that we hear in words like *chair*. So the string *don't you* may be realised as:

- 'doʊntʃu (Gen Am) "donchu"
- 'dəʊntʃu (British RP) "donchu"

Also if the following sound is not alveolar, both the /n/ and the /t/ may change their place of articulation according to the place of the following sound. So for example if the following sound is bilabial, the /nt/ cluster may be realised as /mp/. It is quite common to hear RP speakers saying *I cam'p believe it*, for example.

Comment: And the difference in stress often also leads to a difference in vowel quality (due to reduction of unstressed vowels in the "weak forms" of verbs like *can* and *have*).

Comment: @sumelic Absolutely so.

Comment: The following sound may also be a vowel, which increases the chances of the realisation being [t] ("I don't actually" = /ˌaɪ.doʊn.ˈtæk.ʃə.liː/). Also, just to nitpick, I believe RP refers more to the model or ideal ("BBC English") pronunciation rather than common British pronunciation, so "donchu" and "cam'p" aren't what I would call RP.

Comment: @TimPederick That *ch* assimilation is often used my rather silly people to characterise 'non-standard' English. However, this form of coalescent assimilation is used by the vast majority of RP speakers including the queen.

Comment: I certainly don't mean to say it's "non-standard", much less *bad* (that would be hypocritical of me), and I don't know that I've ever heard the Queen say "don't you" (or "don't use", "want you", etc.), so I'll take you at your word that she says /tʃu/ and not /tju/. Even so, it was my understanding that RP isn't equivalent to "ordinary British"; Wikipedia says that [RP is representative of about 3% of Britons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)!

Comment: @TimPederick We might expect a following vowel to increase the likelihood of a canonical [t], after all we prefer not to use glottal stops prevocalically -  but this doesn't seem to occur with negative contractions. You might enjoy [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199490/are-what-cha-and-arent-cha-examples-of-elision/199501#199501). In particular there's a link to a video of the queen, where you can hear many examples of coalecent assimilation. Coalescent assimilation is part of putative, so-called "ideal English".

Comment: Fascinating, thanks! :-) Although I don't think that illustrates that "this doesn't seem to occur with negative contractions"; after all, /j/ isn't a vowel. And just going anecdotally from my own pronunciation (pretty ordinary Australian, perhaps more enunciated than is typical), I don't *always* pronounce [t] before a vowel, but I'm *far more likely* to than elsewhere.

Comment: @TimPederick It'lll vary between different speakers. My info doesn't come from data about Australian English. It might be the case that it makes it more likely to be a [t] in Australian English!? I don't know :)

Comment: @TimPederick are you from Australia ? Please, broach your opinion to us. In Australia do you pronounce the "t" at the end of "don't", "can't"... ? Or may be do you pronounce it like "doncha" ? Sorry, from the conversation between you and Araucaria above I'm not sure how people usually pronounce that contraction in Australia.

Comment: @Araucaria can you supply a citation for your ranking in "decreasing order of likelihood"?

Comment: I always upvote glottal stops.

Answer (score 6):

[Glottalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottalization) is common in the UK, but whether it is used or not depends on the regional accent. This is not *quite* the same as completely missing the "t" off the end of words, but it might sound as such if you are not used to hearing glottalised consonants.

For non-natives I would not suggest missing the "t" off the end of words consciously. Pronouncing the "t" will not make you sound weird. If you live among native speakers for a while you will probably find yourself naturally adapting to their pronunciation and accent.

Answer (score 4):

At least in my part of the U.S., the "t" is neither fully pronounced nor completely left out, but rather modifies the sound of the preceding "n". Compare "I can think of..." and "I can't think of...". In the second case, the sound of the "n" is much shorter and a noticeable silence occurs before the next word. Whereas in the first case the "n" sound flows right into the next word. It's as if only the first half of the "t" sound is pronounced, with the release left out.

Comment: Simply labeling it (t-)glottalization, though accurate, does not communicate the "modification of the previous 'n' sound" feature I was trying to describe for the OP.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I read your first line, thought out my comment, read the rest of your post, realised that my comment wasn't relevant, and then somehow forgot that and posted it anyway. My apologies.

Comment: No worries! It *is* useful to know that my last sentence *is* a description of what "glottalization" (of "t") means. (The online definitions are so complex that they often obfuscate that.)

Comment: Well, what part of the U.S. are you from ? (I'll know where I cannot understand anything. Joke. :))
I've heard that people from southern states talk similar to people from the UK (anyways, not like people from northern states), 
or if we are talking about so called "glottalization" it doesn't matter and it depends more from a state ?

Comment: @JeffY - Your last sentence is a *great* description of glottalisation, and I agree that trying to understand the online definitions is nigh-on impossible.

Comment: And if you started talking about "can" and "can't" do you agree with that video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3JEpfmbOwI ? (I'm sorry for all these links, I'm really don't want to advertise somebody)
I'm not sure I got what how to make the sound of the "n" is much shorter and the silence before the next word. 
If you had a link to a movie, video where I can listened to pronunciation it would be great !
And, is it right that in the U.S. it's better to not pronounce "can" like we pronounce "car", "bus"... for some reasons... ?

Comment: I am from the Northeast U.S. The Southern U.S. accent is quite distinct (to me) from any British accent. In my experience, the same glottalization I describe above is done in the South, but with a slower speed (drawl) such that the silence/gap I describe is even more noticeable.

Comment: @JeffY perhaps I got what you mean. When you want to say "can go" you pronounce putting the accent on "a" and when you want to say vice versa you pronounce "I" + "k" + "n" pretty fast putting the accent on "kn" and making they sound pretty stronger (especially "k"), right ?

Comment: @Vadim Ahh, the video is describing how best to *listen*, not really how best to speak. And he's giving the worst of "cowboy" pronunciation as "guidance". Yuk. Listen to national news anchors instead for "generic" U.S. pronunciation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpeJqP44nWw

Comment: @Vadim Not really. I am saying take the pronunciation of "can" as here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/can. And as you are saying it, pretend that your car just hit the car in front of you as soon as you reach the "n" sound -- complete stoppage of the breath (glottal stop).

Comment: @JeffY Thanks for the video, I will (although I'm not sure they talk like ordinary people but are taught in special cources).

Comment: @JeffY By the way, that lady (from my second link) she is definitely not from the UK, is she ? And according to her pronounciation and the words she listened to from the Spanish-speaking woman in the cafe (there are pretty lots of Spanish-speaking people in the U.S.), we can guess that she is from the U.S. So, it appears that both ways are common and if you listen to another person and whether that person pronounce "t" or not, you won't pay attention to that fact or it'll be sound non natural ?

Comment: The young lady in the second link is possibly Canadian. And she mispronounces "pronunciation" of all things. Don't take advice from YouTube videos is my advice.

Comment: @JeffY oh, gosh. I can't thank you enough for your patience and advices. If I still don't pester you with questions and you will have your time and desire please share your opinion about http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295649/how-to-pronounce-do-you-would-you-and-their-negative-contractions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should pronounce the "t" of negative "n't", unless you don't pronounce any "t"s in this position after "n".  That is, in the American English I'm familiar with, the "t" might be lost, but it is not especially vulnerable to loss because it's part of a negative contraction.

All the alveolar stops, "t/d/n", are often lost or assimilate in position to a following stop.  "t/d" can delete after a consonant (other than a glide or liquid) and before an initial consonant of the next word, for instance.  Along with the other stops "p/k", "t" can glottalize before a following consonant, then the glottal "t" can lose its tongue closure and become just a glottal stop.

Answer (score -1):

As an Englishman I watched, more in sorrow than anger, the video of the American lady teaching bad English pronunciation. Missing off the "t" when pronouncing words like "don't" and "wouldn't" is every bit as bad as doing the same for words like "hunt" and "count". Don't do it! It's just lazy.

I would just add that well-educated American friends of mine pronounce these words correctly. They, like me, have lived and worked in countries where English is not the first language and so clear pronunciation is an important communication skill.

Comment: Maybe you should write to the queen and tell her that she can't speak English properly :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
I've got a "New Total English book for Pre-Intermediate" (it's published by the UK, I suppose) and it says that
"When two consonants are next to each other, one of the consonants is often not pronounced.
You shouldn' smoke. You can' come in here."
So, is it up to date information ? 
I mean, is it natural information that is used ordinary people in the UK (or may be it's just an old academic rule) ?

Comment: @Vadim Yes, that information is correct.

Comment: @Vadim 50 years ago the upper classes said things like "huntin', shootin' and fishin'" whereas everybody else said "hunting, shooting and fishing". When a book can't differentiate between "You can come in here" meaning "You can come in here" and "You can' come in here" meaning "you can't come in here" you know it is giving bad advice.

Comment: @BrianTowers Excuse me, but that book was published in Harlow, England. You suppose that infromation is wrong, right ? And do you always pronounce "t" at the end of such words as "shouldn't", "can't ? I thought that information is pretty correct at least for the cases when we say "can't" just because we can distinguish "can" and "can't" pronouncing the second one the same way like we pronounce vowel in "bus", "car"...

Comment: @BrianTowers: It may be bad advice for your dialect, if you have the same vowel in "can" and "can't", but for those of us with the [trap–bath split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8a%E2%9F%A9#Trap.E2.80.93bath_split) (or even those who just lengthen the vowel in "can't"), it's not a problem.

Comment: @BrianTowers Try [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlB373yzVTY) for an introduction to how we actually differentiate between normal auxiliaries and negative contractions.

Comment: @Araucaria the Queen doesn't miss the t off.

Comment: @JamesRyan Video of [the Queen talking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lh1-9ww_HmM). At 0.52 you can hear "you can**ʔ** really divide it up".

Comment: Are you kidding?  I've read some ignorant things on this site, but this takes the cake.  Only educated people pronounce their Ts?  I didn know I wasn educa'ed.  I'd love to watch you announce this in a pub in Scotland.

Comment: @Araucaria where do people come up with these sort of ideas about pronunciation?

Comment: @JamesRyan [the queen talking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lh1-9ww_HmM) and at 3.37 "I wouldnbe happy if I just had arable farming" where the /t/ has been completely elided from *wouldn't*. I'm interested in where your evidence that the queen never elides her /t/s came from?

Comment: @michael_timofeev No idea old bean ... :/

Comment: @Araucaria funny because this very issue came up in class today...students have a hell of a time with can and can't.

Comment: @Araucaria this answer just irritates me to no end...only educated people pronounce English the right way!

Comment: @michael_timofeev Have you seen this video? It's great! [Can / can't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlB373yzVTY)

Comment: @Araucaria my approach lately is to help them hear the sound.  But I teach them to use "cannot" so that they cane be understood.

Comment: @michael_timofeev What you'll find is that it's actually the positive form that is going to cause the problems. Especially if they speak to Gen American speakers. Because "We CAN do it" will be understood as "we can't do it", because of the stress and the lack of a weak form.

Comment: @Araucaria maybe you are unable to discern the subtlety but it is definately not missed out entirely

Comment: @Araucaria are you sure?  What about the down tone on "can't"?

Comment: @JamesRyan It is. I checked out the waveform. It's voiced all the way through, so there's no doubt about it. Our brains are quite funny though, yours is probably putting it in. Took a year of training for me to be able to really hear (kinda) what's going on when listening to something. But I trust a simple waveform more than my ears.

Comment: @Araucaria if it weren't for the tones in can and can't native speakers wouldn't be able to understand...context is usually not a helper.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Have you watched that video? It's really helpful! Can is normally /kn/ when unstressed. It's the stress that tells us more than anything else.

Comment: @Araucaria I have...it doesn't replicate normal speech...its ESL friendly...the tonal difference between a "yes / can" and "no / can't" statement is very distinct in authentic speech.

Comment: @Araucaria btw, you should locate a copy of her book "sound advice."  I have two copies and use it for the last two years with good results.

Comment: @michael_timofeev The examples in the exercises are natural enough. But it's the weak forms/strong forms and stress that get us to distinguish between positive and negative, not tone! Honest :D

Comment: @Araucaria maybe we are talking about the same thing...when you say "can't" your pitch goes down abruptly as does the rest of the sentence.  Maybe in AmE it's more pronounced...anyway, it's one of the "mysteries of English" that keeps us employed.

Comment: Dude, you're giving prescriptivism a bad name by calling people who don't speak your variety lazy. Dumb lambs to the slaughter! Failing to pronounce words the way our Anglo-Saxon forbears meant. Damn the French!! (BTW I haven't watched the video)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33584/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-towers-do-we-pronounce-a-t-sound-in-negative-con).