# How to pronounce "do you", "would you" and their negative contractions

Tags: pronunciation

I don't know now how to pronounce phrases like "do you", "would you" and their negative contractions.

For a while ago I though it's correct to pronounce "do/would you" (and even have [not] + V3) separately as well as use contraction form.
But it turned out that not contraction form assigns another more stronger meaning. And in common situations it's preferable to use a contraction form 
to not outline emphasize in those situations where it doesn't need to.
But I've found some cases I don't know what to do with:
There was a scene I heard where a British lady said
"Do you two
(like "Dzhu too", there was a week "zh" sound (here I'm trying to express sounds not the meaning, I got what she said))
have any plans to the evening ?"
And after some time and phrases another lady (seems from Canada) asked the first one "Do you ("Due", no sound "zh") have any suggestions?"

From another scene I heard some person said (I don't know where that person was from) "would you" like "woo'zhu".

So, how to pronounce these phrases ? 
Should I put sound "ch" 
(like from the song "Don't cha" performed by The Pussycat Dolls feat. Busta Rhymes (but there was "don't cha" = don't you))
or "zh" 
(if we are talking about "would you", "do you")
?
By the way, how to pronounce "wouldn't you" ? I've never heard any "ch", "zh" sounds in that phrase ))))

Answer (score 2):

In rapid speech in many varieties of English, "you" comes out as "ya" when unstressed

and (separately) a dental ('t' or 'd') before "you" often merges with the 'y' to form 'ch' or 'j'.

Most people don't even notice these changes, and will not make them when speaking carefully.

The latter change ('t' -> 'ch' and 'd' -> 'j') happens for many people whenever a 'y' semi-vowel sound follows (including in the vowel written 'ue'). Examples: "tune" -> "chune", "due" -> "jue"; and nearly everybody pronounces the suffix "-ture" as though it were written "-cher".

Comment: That's fine but it would be nice to listen how you pronounce "don't you", "would you" and "do you" ? How do your friends or relatives pronounce these phrases and in your opinion what people are many ? Those who pronounce "ch"/"j" or another ones ? And, where are you from ? Thanks !

Comment: I pronounce all those with all the variations mentioned, depending on context, how carefully I'm speaking, what I'm stressing. So the first can come out as "don't you", "donchoo" or "doncha", and similarly for the others.