# linking s/z and y

Tags: pronunciation

I realize some native speakers will create a new sound when linking s/z and y [j]. For example:

Miss you = [mɪʃuː] "mishu"

As you = [/æʒuː] "azhu"

Is it okay if I just say [mɪsjuː] for "miss you" and [æzjuː] for "as you"?
Do native speakers always do that specific linking sound?
Is it stigmatized in any way?

Comment: Discussed some here: [Are what-cha and arent-cha examples of elision?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199490/are-what-cha-and-arent-cha-examples-of-elision/199501#199501)

Comment: It's acceptable, and will not raise any eyebrows; but there is usually a slight retention of the original sibilant (elided *miss you* does not sound **exactly** like *tissue*), and if you don't reproduce that it will sound a little odd. And I see no reason why you spend any effort trying to reproduce the elision when the unelided pronunciation is just as acceptable. Put your energy somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except perhaps for the devoicing of [j], all of the changes from [sj] to [ʃ] are optional, so far as I can tell.  We have [mɪsju], [mɪsj̥u], [mɪsçu], [mɪsʃu], [mɪʃʃu], [mɪʃu] by various assimilations.  It's interesting to try characterizing the differences from "I miss shoes", "I miss Hughes".